# Extreme Notification Device - How To

Tags: .net, continuous-integration

Can anyone point me to instructions on how to make a red(broken)/green(OK)/yellow(building) Extreme Notification Device with lamps that hooks into CruiseControl.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking to propose something similar in my project (we use Jenkins). You might find useful some info I have found:

- As a start point you can check CruiseControl config [help](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#x10).
- I was reading a blog entry about that: http://www.therealjoshanderson.com/2010/04/ledbloa-ftw-my-teams-new-build-status.html
- There is also a book that I have here: O'Reilly [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010326.do) called **Jenkins, The definitive Guide.** from John Ferguson Smart that has a chapter about it. Maybe you can use its information to adapt it to CruiseControl.